# How to set ball's random position in Spritekit?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am making a game where there are two balls on the scene, but the user is going to tap on the correct ball. However, when user taps on the correct ball, I want to set a random position for my second ball that when the user taps on the correct ball, I want to also want the second ball to move randomly.
Here is my code for setting up the random positions of the ball:

```
let currentBall = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: CGFloat(size))
let shape = SKShapeNode()

  currentBall.fillColor = pickColor()

 //Rectangle
shape.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: 64, y: 64, width: 160,height: 160), cornerRadius: 50).cgPath

    shape.fillColor = pickColor()

    self.addChild(shape)

 func randomBallPosition() -> CGPoint {
        let xPosition = view!.scene!.frame.midX - viewMidX + CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(viewMidX*2)))
        let yPosition = view!.scene!.frame.midY - viewMidY + CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(viewMidY*2)))


        return CGPoint(x: xPosition, y: yPosition)

    }


   func handleTap() {
          currentBall.position = randomBallPosition()
         shape.position = randomBallPosition()

    }
```

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're setting the exact same position, which you have used for the first ball. As far as I understand both ball should appear at random independent positions. You should create a function to return a new position and call it for each ball:

```
class MyScene: SKScene {
    var currentBall: SKShapeNode!
    var shape: SKShapeNode!

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        super.didMove(to: view)

        let currentBall = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: CGFloat(size))
        currentBall.fillColor = pickColor()

        let shape = SKShapeNode()
        shape.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: 64, y: 64, width: 160,height: 160), cornerRadius: 50).cgPath
        shape.fillColor = pickColor()
        self.addChild(shape)
    }

    func handleTap() {
        //your code here, except that you don't create new nodes, just modify existing ones
        //at some point you will change balls' positions like this:
        currentBall.position = randomBallPosition()
        secondBall.position = randomBallPosition()
    }

    func randomBallPosition() -> CGPoint {
        let xPosition = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32((view?.bounds.maxX)! + 1)))
        let yPosition = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32((view?.bounds.maxY)! + 1)))
        return CGPoint(x: xPosition, y: yPosition)
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you. That works. But having this small issue as well,. when applying the function, and now when user taps on the  balls it just duplicates the second ball over and over again.

Comment: You should not create a new `shape` every time. Create it once into a scene variable and then just update it's position and hide/unhide whenever needed.

Comment: hey Alex, I tried the same way you have wrote the code above, is not working the way I wanted. The currentBall works good but the secondBall just doesn't go once. Every time user taps on the ball the secondBall duplicates. I tried not to put a new shape every time. But can't figure it out. Do you know any kind of solution to try ?

Comment: Can you plese update your question with your current code?

Comment: any ideas? @alexburtnik

Comment: @SuzyHakobyan I've updated the code, try it again. You should do that balls setup in `didMoveToView` function, not in the class scope (it won't complile at all)

Comment: let currentBall = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: CGFloat(size)) in didMoveToView gives an error: "Cannot invoke initializer for type 'CGFloat with an argument".